# Node.JS req.body String Too Long?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I am once again asking a probably beginners question, but I have looked around quite a bit, and was unable to find the answer I need. I have created a Node.JS server pulling data for a Game State Integration project I am working on, and I need to request certain data from the game.

Basically, what is happening in the code is I am setting the variable `newKillStatus` to a certain part of the player_state file from which I am reading. Before I talk a bit further, here is the code I am using: (If you need more, please ask)

```
fs.readFile('player_state', 'utf8', function(err, killStatus) {
    var player = 'player' in req.body ? req.body.player : null;
    if (player && player.state !== killStatus) {
        var newKillStatus = req.body.player.state.round_kills;
        if (!newKillStatus) {
            newKillStatus = '';
        }
        fs.writeFile('player_state', newKillStatus);
        console.log(newKillStatus);
    }
});
```

So as you can see I am trying to set `newKillStatus` to `req.body.state.round_kills;` which, from what I can understand is too long, because when I try to start the server, it gives me this error:

> cannot read property 'round_kills' of undefined

But If I get rid of the `round_kills` part it gives me `round_kills`, but it also gives me a whole bunch of other statistics that I don't want to set the variable to.

So basically my only question is how can I set `var newKillStatus` to `req.body.player.state.round_kills` without an error.

Thank you for helping!

**EDIT:**
I have tried all the solutions and multiple combinations of strings, is it possible that the underscore is creating an error?

Comment: No, it's not "too long". It just doesn't exist. There is no `req.body.player.state`, and accessing `.round_kills` on that throws an exception. Either you got a typo and meant `req.body.state.round_kills`, or your serialisation or parsing of the request body is insufficient.

Comment: That's very odd, because If I just use `req.body.state` round_kills will show up with the unneeded info, and if I use `req.body.state.health` which is another piece of info in that section is works. So could it posiblly be due to the underscore, because round_killhs doesn't work either. (Another data point)

Comment: Yes, you really have a typo. Use `req.body.state.round_kills` instead of `req.body.player.state.round_kills`. No `.player`!

Comment: I have tried getting rid of the .player , same error, getting rid of .state wouldn't create an error, but would not log the data, and I'm guessing wasn't receiving it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several attempts to find the answer myself, I have found it. I am actually quite surprised it took me so long to spot this. The probably was actually above what I though was causing it, and what the error said was causing it. The problem was actually in `var player = 'player' in req.body ? req.body.player : null;` I needed to change `req.body.player` to `req.body.player.state` do the code below would know what I referencing.